# Is it okay to post a one-line answer, or would those be better as comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, comments-as-answers

I always find it difficult to differentiate between a comment and an answer when I feel like the question can be "answered" in one line. But I'm generally reluctant to post an answer because I feel like I'm not being detailed enough. If you look at blackcompe's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117437/frequency-of-items-in-int-as-opposed-to-listinteger), it is technically correct as it stands. But should it have more detail to actually qualify as an answer and not a comment?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your proposed response can stand alone and actually answers the question, then it's perfectly okay to post it as an answer. Otherwise, you should post it as a comment.

Of course, obviously the *better* answers will generally be longer than one line. To bulk up the content, you might consider doing things like:

- linking to the appropriate documentation
- including a code sample
- suggesting a superior alternative approach
- cautioning against some things that people in the same situation commonly do wrong
- adding superfluous bulleted lists

I will frequently post a comment instead of an answer when I'm either guessing at a solution, providing only a hint or a link, or otherwise unable/unwilling to write a complete answer. Ideally, someone else (including, potentially, the asker) will come along and expand my suggestion into a full answer.

Comment: +1 superfluous bulleted lists. noted. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the policy of demoting simple answers to comments is hiding good, terse, answers in the comments section. I know at least I skip over them, because they rarely have good information.

So to answer your question: Yes, they need to be more complete to get past the moderators, even though they are technically fine without the unnecessary explanations.